# Bluetooth чат с использованием BluetoothSocket

Tags: android, bluetooth

По [примеру из GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatService.java) делаю приложение - чат.
Сейчас у меня работает чат только для 2х устройств.
Возможно ли сделать так чтобы открывались несколько BluetoothSocket `ы т.е. 
например в радиусе действия блютуз есть 4 устройства, нужно чтобы они приконнектились друг к другу (программно device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                            MY_UUID_INSECURE);) и не закрывали сокет связи.. Чтобы все 4 устройства в один момент могли отправлять друг другу сообщения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В англоязычном стаковерфлове есть тема в котором есть пример с подключением 7 устроиств
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943182/multiple-bluetooth-connection

Answer (score 0):

Что то мне подсказывает, что это технически не возможно. В виду того, что BlueTooth не имеет возможности множественного подключения. Только пара.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943182/multiple-bluetooth-connection